# Sidekiq repeating the same job over and over

Tags: carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am essentially writing the project in [Railscast 383](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3) - the second part, when the photo is uploaded directly to AWS S3, and the photo is then processed in the background by Sidekiq to create a thumbnail version of the photo. I'm on Rails 4.

My issue is that the Sidekiq job, after completing successfully, keeps repeating over and over, instead of just stopping.

Where am I going wrong? I can't see any difference between my code and that of the Railscast, other than I'm on Rails 4 (so strong parameters instead of `attr_accessible`)

Photo class:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  default_scope order('updated_at DESC')

  after_save :enqueue_image

  def image_name
    File.basename(image.path || image.filename) if image
  end

  def enqueue_image
    ImageWorker.perform_async(id, key) if key.present?
  end
end
```

ImageWorker:

```
class ImageWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options retry: false
  # sidekiq_options retry: 3

  def perform(id, key)
    photo = Photo.find(id)
    photo.key = key
    photo.remote_image_url = photo.image.direct_fog_url(with_path: true)
    photo.save!
    photo.update_column(:image_processed, true)
  end
end
```

Uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  # storage :fog
  #### storage defaults to fog when CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader is included ####

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
  end

  version :medium do
    process :resize_to_limit => [400, 400]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason for the sidekiq worker to be called again and again is because the `perform_async` is called every time you save your photo object, which occurs within the sidekiq worker itself.
So every time the `ImageWorker` is called, it saves the photo, calling the `ImageWorker` again, creating the loop you are experiencing.

Are you sure you aren't missing a check for the `:image_processed` tag to be true before calling the `ImageWorker` again.
Try this:

```
def enqueue_image
    ImageWorker.perform_async(id, key) if key.present? && !image_processed
end
```

This will check if the image was processed once before. I think this was probably meant to be set in the rails cast but the author forgot about it, otherwise the image_processed flag is obsolete.